# CakePHP Using both Id and Title in URL

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create a link like: `/favours/20201/This_is_a_favour` using both the id and the favour title.

I have set up the link like:

```
<h3><?php echo $this->Html->link($favour['Favour']['title'], array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'view',$favour['Favour']['id'], Inflector::slug($favour['Favour']['title']))); ?></h3>
```

and the controller action SO FAR is:

```
function view ( $id, $title )
{
    $favour = $this->Favour->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array('Favour.title' => $title)
    ));

    if (empty($favour))
    {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
    $this->set(compact('favour'));
}

Router::connect('/favours/:id/:favourName',array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'view'),
        array(
            'favourName'=>'[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+',
            'pass'=>array('favourName')
        ),
        array('id' => '[0-9]+')
    );
```

However I get a 404 at the moment?

**NOTE: I don't want to use the sluggable plugin or store slugs in the DB!**

Comment: Should you even collect/care/acknowledge that "favourName" exists in this case? It's been awhile since I've messed with Cake routing, but isn't there a way to only capture the "/:id/[anything]"? Then the controller can (optionally) check if the given title matches, and IF NOT it will then do a simple redirect to "/:id/[proper title]", which will work. (This whole thing causes some extra lookups). Stack Overflow does the same thing with URLs/IDs.

Comment: Any chance you could post this as an answer with some code? Thanks

Comment: Also Stackoverflow DOES redirect! If you type just http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718606/ it redirects you to this question but with the title in the url!

Comment: huh! You're right! It didn't always, as I remember that being a point of discussion in a past Q/A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to set up your route in `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/favours/:id',
                array('controller' => 'favors', 'action' => 'view'),
                array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'pass' => array('id')));

Router::connect('/favours/:id/:slug',
                array('controller' => 'favors', 'action' => 'view'),
                array(
                    'id'   => '[0-9]+',
                    'slug' => '[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+',
                    'pass' => array('id', 'slug')
                ));
```

Then I'd recommend to add a method to your Favour model that handles the creating of the `:slug` parameter, since you'll have to use this from different places and you may want to change how exactly it works later:

```
public static function slug(array $favour) {
    // good enough for now, might want to change this later
    return Inflector::slug($favour['title']);
}
```

Then, whenever you make a link, do it like this:

```
array('controller' => 'favours', 'action' => 'view',
      'id' => $favour['Favour']['id'], 'slug' => Favour::slug($favour['Favour']))
```

Your controller action simply looks like this:

```
public function view($id, $slug) {
    $favour = $this->Favour->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Favour.id' => $id)));
    if (!$favour) {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
    if (Favour::slug($favour['Favour']) != $slug) {
        $this->redirect(array('id' => $id, 'slug' => Favour::slug($favour['Favour'])));
    }

    $this->set(compact('favour'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks ;) Glad someone finally came in who knew what I meant!

Comment: One issue though. If the user goes to `favours/2/` then they get 404 errors! They should be redirected to the post still. How do I deal with a missing slug?

Comment: I've tried `if(Inflector::slug($favour['Favour']['title']) != $slug || !$slug)` but no luck :/

Comment: Then you need to create another route for `Router::connect('/favours/:id', ...)`, otherwise the route doesn't match.

Comment: Could you show an example? I didn't know you could have two routes for one action call?

Comment: You can have as many routes as you want, the only question is which one first matches a URL and which one reverse-matches when you *create* a URL/link. Added example.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Story (core developer of CakePHP) writes up how to do what you want - a few minor tweaks from his article should get you there in good shape (don't be disheartened by the title of his post).
http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp

Comment: That's overkill for what I want to do! I'd rather just get what I have above working.

Comment: I haven't yet! I was hoping to get a reply for that too! I'll show what I have so far.

Comment: What does the rest of your routing setup look like - are you sure you're hitting your rule before another rule takes care of it?

Comment: Yes! The only other rule is the default pages one! But that's the least of my worries at the moment as a) the controller action isn't dealing with the id and b) doesn't handle the redirect

Answer (score 0):

why so complicated?
simply use canonical - thats what it is for

```
/controller/action/id/some-slugged-title
```

is the canonical link - but

```
/controller/action/id/
```

and

```
/controller/action/id/some-slugged-ti
```

and

```
/controller/action/id/some-slugged-title-blabla
```

would all work, too. via canonical the search engines know what the correct one is

SEO is fine here. And no additional redirect necessary (less server consuming).
Additionally you will not get 404s if the slug/title change. 
this is a huge risk with many other solutions.

Comment: Hi I have no idea where what you have posted would go? Also the 404s would never happen as the ID would never change and it would just redirect to the correct SLUG if it was wrong/changed!

Comment: function view ($id = null) {}  more is not necessary. and in the view display the canonical link. thats all.

Comment: But it doesn't do what I asked in my OP

Comment: "CakePHP Using both Id and Title in URL" - I just told you that your approach might not be the best solution. unnecessary redirects are neither for the user nor for the server a good thing. check out other sites like "http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2079-shellin-problems-with-zero" they use the same approach (although they seem to be missing the canonical).

Answer (score 0):

```
    function view ( $id = null, $slug = null )
    {
        $this->Favour->id = $id;
        $this->set('favour', $this->Favour->read());
    }

    Router::connect('/favours/:id/:slug',array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'view'),
        array(
            'pass' => array('id','slug'),
            'id' => '[0-9]+'
        )
    );

<?php echo $this->Html->link($favour['Favour']['title'], array('controller'=>'favours','action'=>'view','id'=>$favour['Favour']['id'], 'slug'=>Inflector::slug($favour['Favour']['title']))); ?>
```